# Problem regarding with Output in 1-D arrays and 2-D arrays in the same senerio

Tags: python

*I have an Empty array and suppose if I want to insert the value using **insert** method as in code,

```
arr = []
arr.insert(0,101)
arr.insert(1,200)
arr.insert(2,20)
print(arr)
```

The output is: [101, 200, 20]

*but when I am calling the same method by take the value from user, taking 0th index and 1 value*

```
arr = []
index, *value = input("Enter your index and value")
arr.insert(int(index), value)
print(arr)
```

The Output is in double array : [['1']]

please help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you want to use value as a pointer like in c++ so you add "*" before value.
I just print the value and the output is a list.

```
arr = []
index, *value = input("Enter your index and value")
print(value)
#output:['2']
```

Then i did some modification to your code and it works

```
arr = []
index= input("Enter your index: ")
value=input("Enter your value: ")
arr.insert(int(index), value)
print(arr)

#run
Enter your index: 1
Enter your value: 101
['101']
```

Comment: I am Using python and as per you, you have taken 2 different input as an index, and value, in this case the output will be fine , but I am taking 2 input by user at a time. so in this case it will not work.. And * sign is use to take multiple arguments in python while take input by user

Comment: as far as i know, "*" will transfer the var to a tuple. Like a=(1,2), *a is [1,2]. If you want to read multiple input at one time. You can try to use .split(). eg: index,value=input().split()

Comment: My problem is regarding with 1d and 2D array. As the output is showing in [[ ]] but i want to insert the data in [ ]

Comment: Yes, I know. What i mean is you should delete the "*" symbol, and get 2 input at one time use the index,value=input().split() command.  Then everything works well. If you insist on adding the "*", python will consider the value to be a tuple(lead to the 2d array) .